# How can i change the line content with another with grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, preg-replace, task

I have a simple task,

when i write the command "grunt build" i want this 2 lines to change state, like so:

before the command:

```
        baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'
        //baseUrl : 'http://188.166.18.108/'
```

after the command

```
        //baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'
        baseUrl : 'http://188.166.18.108/'
```

end of build change back to:

```
        baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'
        //baseUrl : 'http://188.166.18.108/'
```

Is it anyway possible with grunt to do so? thanks guys!

Comment: Where is this content located? Into a js file?

Comment: yep, inside a directory full of js files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace), like this:

```
'string-replace': {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: 'path/to/your/file',
      dest: 'path/to/your/file'
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: "baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'",
        replacement: "baseUrl : 'http://188.166.18.108:3000/'"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can have only one line in your file, without having to comment it.

```
baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

Also, if you want to replace all occurrences of *localhost*, you can use it as a pattern and it will replace all to your *IP address*:

```
...
pattern: "localhost",
replacement: "188.166.18.108"
...
```

For changing back from the *IP address* to *localhost* you can add a new task for string replace and run both in your build. It will be something like:

```
'string-replace': {
  prev: {
    files: {
      src: 'path/to/your/file',
      dest: 'path/to/your/file'
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: "baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'",
        replacement: "baseUrl : 'http://188.166.18.108:3000/'"
      }]
    }
  },
  after: {
    files: {
      src: 'path/to/your/file',
      dest: 'path/to/your/file'
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: "baseUrl : 'http://188.166.18.108:3000/'",
        replacement: "baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/'"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

And then run it like:

```
grunt.registerTask('replace', ['string-replace:prev', 'string-replace:after']);
```